# Finding specific data within a file array?

Tags: java, arrays, file

Ok, so my program takes a file (the file is 401 by 401 numbers separated by one space) and writes them into an array, and it then splits up the data and prints it out. After doing this, I want to tell the program to find specific numbers out of this file (mainly, the highest number and the lowest number). I have tried methods such as mathmax and mathmix, so if the array were called " dataArray" I have tried to say "Math.max(dataArray, 0)" But htis has failed. I have tried other solutions after searching this site, but nothing has worked. Can someone please help me to find data in this array? Thanks a lot, here's the code so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;  //import tools

public class MultiArray {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        //variables
        int rows = 401;
        int columns = 401;
        String file = "dmt.asc";

        double dmtData[][] = new double[rows][columns];  //array

        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //read the file

        //split the numbers and write to array
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            String rowArray [] = Reader.readLine().split(" ");
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                dmtData[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(rowArray[j]);
            }
        }

        Reader.close();  //close the reader and the file

        //print out the array
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                System.out.println(dmtData[i][j]);
            }
        }

        //code here to find highest number
        System.out.println("The highest peak in this area is: ");

        //code here to find lowest number
        System.out.println("The lowest dip in this area is: ");

    }

}
```

Oh, if you are trying to run the code to understand how it works and need the file I used, please E-Mail me and I will send it to you, I really appreciate any help what so ever :) My E-Mail is Spooce199@hotmail.co.uk    Hope everyone had a lovely christmas :)

Comment: Can you show some input data from your file? Some input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been great if you  have attached the file somehow... but, from the looks of it, I think this

```
    double high = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double low = Double.MAX_VALUE; 

    for(int i = 0; i < dmtData.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dmtData[i].length; j++){
            if(dmtData[i][j] > high){
                high = dmtData[i][j];
            }
            else if(dmtData[i][j] < low){
                low = dmtData[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

should get the max Values and low Values from dmtData. I didn't test it so try it or past dmt.asc in paste bin and include the link .

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add a text file, only photo files :/ Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try this out later :)

Comment: only one thing is that "low" should be initialised with a really high number. Otherwise it will never change.